# efficient way to write using Netty

Tags: java, netty

Does Netty provide any way for me to avoid buffer copying when I am writing objects to network ? In its `Channel.write(Object)` , in my understanding, this object is made to pass through encoders ( which return ChannelBuffer copies ). This basically means for each message I end up creating a buffer copy , eventually creating large number of short lived buffer objects

Can Netty provide me with a reusable ChannelBuffer that I fill up with bytes and it writes these bytes to network directly ?

Answer (score 0):

Netty already recycles buffers, you don't need to care about this.

Also, the encoders/decoders are only the ones you wrote yourself, Netty can only handle **ChannelBuffer** objects, if you are writing a ChannelBuffer to your channel there is no magic around it, it's contents are written directly to the output.

What you can (and should) do is to create buffers of the exact size you need to avoid allocation of dynamic buffers when you are loading the buffer with data.

Comment: what do you mean by 'Netty already recycles buffers' ? ChannelBuffers.buffer() will create new buffer everytime - only a gc will recycle them ?

Comment: Whoops, my bad, it isn't implemented yet - https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/62